# how to pass value between two process (.net c# exe)

Tags: c#, desktop

I have an application (C# desktop app) which is launched from another c# application. For passing value from parent 
app to the child app we are using a text file. The parent app before launching it, writes the values in 
a text file and the child app reads it.

The child app process the value and calculates a result.

Problem: Once the user closes the child app, the parent app needs to be notified and the new value should be
available in the parent app.

Now I am not at all sure how we can achieve this in a simple way? The architecture cannot be changed.

Thanks a lot in advance.
Best regards.

Comment: Are your values numeric or character based?

Comment: This would be a too broad and oppinionated answer. There are dozens of ways you can communicate inter-processes... I'd check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx) for a starting guide. For .NET and simple local (non-network) communication, I'd go for [Anonymous Pipes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546102.aspx), but this is just an oppinion

Comment: I have heard that we can may be use WCF service ?

I do not know wcf much but what I know about WCF service is that an app will have an reference to the wcf service which will call a method say MyMethod. Now MyMethod() performs some functionality and once the functionality is over wcf service can make a callback to the calling app with the result.

But in my scenario there is a different process that the parent app launches. In this case how wcf service can be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have heard that we can may be use WCF service ?

I do not know wcf much but what I know about WCF service is that an app will have an reference to the wcf service which will call a method say MyMethod. Now MyMethod() performs some functionality and once the functionality is over wcf service can make a callback to the calling app with the result.

But in my scenario there is a different process that the parent app launches. In this case how wcf service can be used?

Answer (score 0):

How complex and/or large are the values you are sending?

If you want, you could use [MSMQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978430.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html) (links point to tutorials). IMO, this is decent for larger messages and will stay out there incase your app crashes, the message will still be out there waiting for next time.

Or for an old-school approach on integer based values, **SendMessage API** using [WM_APP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644930(v=vs.85).aspx) +(*custom index*) as the message type.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this.  Your parent app could poll for changes in the text file.  You could use a socket between the parent and child processes (a network service call bound to localhost).  You could write to a message queue.

Comment: Ahh yes, sockets! That one slipped my mind when doing my response. Good addition.